# Перебор текста из столбца по ключевым словам

Tags: sql

Есть ли в sql такая штука как перебор текста по ключевым словам? К примеру есть 2 таблицы: t1.id, t1.message и t2.class, t2.keywords. Можно ли как то сделать сопоставление t1.message и t2.keywords и в случае совпадения присваивать строке из t1 значения из t2.class?

*Извиняюсь если что то непонятно написал, я в sql недавно*

Comment: Можно, но пока что нельзя. Определите, что нужно делать, если одному message соответствует более одного keyword. И укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. *присваивать строке из t1 значения из t2.class* Какой такой строке? В терминах SQL есть таблицы, записи и поля, строка - это тип данных поля либо тип значения нетипизованной переменной.

Comment: Уточните, какой СУБД пользуетесь? SQL разный бывает.

Comment: Нужно чтобы запрос перебирал весь текст в message и и прри соответствии более одного keyword писваивал записи значение t2.class т.е. на выходе должно получится что то вроде id, message, class

Comment: Субд heidisql 9.5.0.5196

Comment: HeidiSQL - это не СУБД, а клиент (интерфейс) для некоей СУБД.

Comment: *прри соответствии более одного keyword писваивал записи значение t2.class* Желательно сперва думать, а потом говорить. С одним keyword - вопросов нет. Но при соответствии более чем одному keyword возможны варианты: вернуть самый первый (при какой сортировке?), самый последний (то же), вернуть все (CSV-списком), вернуть все уникальные (CSV-списком), не присваивать вообще (вернуть пустой), не возвращать такую запись, ...